# Rspec: expect(response).to render_template(file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html") fails

Tags: rspec-rails

I can't figure out the reason of this failing RSpec controller spec:

```rb
      it 'renders the 404 page when the tenant is inactive' do
        allow(MyService).to receive(:call).and_return(true)
        post :some_route, params: my_params
        expect(response).to render_template(file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html")        
      end
```

The test fails with:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false)
       Expected [] to include "/Users/my_rails_app/public/404.html".
```

It works on Rails `5.2.4` version but fails on Rails `6.1.5`.
I asserted the status code to be `404` and it was correct. The response does contain the content of my custom `404.html` page.

The method that returns the custom `404` page is defined as follows:

```rb
def render_404_html
  render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: :not_found
end
```

Any ideas?